# How to Iterating through an JSON Object and append an HTML input menu/list select

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, getjson

I've searched on here and tried several solutions offered with no luck. I have a html input menu/list select that I want to populate with options after the user inputs into an input text box. Once the user enters the parameter I want javascript to call a php page and return an array/object with the menu options.

**sample of my html:**

```
<select name="celestrials" id="celestrials" onFocus="updateCelestrials()">
<option value="Choose...">n/a</option>
</select>
```

**my javascript in the html file(in same folder as the json.php file used in var myURL below):**

```
function updateCelestrials () {
    var orbs = document.getElementById('systemNames').value;

    var myURL = "http://www.domain.com/folder/json.php?solarSystemName="+orbs;

    $.getJSON(myURL, function(data) {
      $.each(data, function() { 
        $("<option value='" + data + "'>" + data + "</option>").appendTo("#celestrials");
      });
    });
}
```

**my array returned by php:**

```
echo json_encode($arrayItems, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

**and finally my retuned array/object trimmed down for summary:**

```
{"0":"YHN-3K I","1":"YHN-3K II","2":"YHN-3K III"}
```

**Full array:**

```
{"0":"YHN-3K I","1":"YHN-3K II","2":"YHN-3K III","3":"YHN-3K IV","4":"YHN-3K IV - Moon 1","5":"YHN-3K V","6":"YHN-3K VI","7":"YHN-3K VI - Moon 1","8":"YHN-3K VII","9":"YHN-3K VIII","10":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 1","11":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 2","12":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 3","13":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 4","14":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 5","15":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 6","16":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 7","17":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 8","18":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 9","19":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 10","20":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 11","21":"YHN-3K VIII - Moon 12","22":"YHN-3K IX","23":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 1","24":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 2","25":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 3","26":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 4","27":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 5","28":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 6","29":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 7","30":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 8","31":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 9","32":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 10","33":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 11","34":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 12","35":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 13","36":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 14","37":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 15","38":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 16","39":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 17","40":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 18","41":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 19","42":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 20","43":"YHN-3K IX - Moon 21","44":"YHN-3K X","45":"YHN-3K X - Moon 1","46":"YHN-3K X - Moon 2","47":"YHN-3K X - Moon 3","48":"YHN-3K X - Moon 4","49":"YHN-3K X - Moon 5","50":"YHN-3K X - Moon 6","51":"YHN-3K X - Moon 7","52":"YHN-3K X - Moon 8","53":"YHN-3K X - Moon 9","54":"YHN-3K X - Moon 10","55":"YHN-3K X - Moon 11","56":"YHN-3K X - Moon 12","57":"YHN-3K X - Moon 13","58":"YHN-3K X - Moon 14","59":"YHN-3K X - Moon 15","60":"YHN-3K X - Moon 16","61":"YHN-3K X - Moon 17","62":"YHN-3K X - Moon 18","63":"YHN-3K X - Moon 19","64":"YHN-3K XI","65":"YHN-3K XI - Moon 1","66":"YHN-3K XI - Moon 2","67":"YHN-3K XI - Moon 3","68":"YHN-3K XI - Moon 4","69":"YHN-3K XI - Moon 5","70":"YHN-3K XI - Moon 6","71":"YHN-3K XI - Moon 7","72":"YHN-3K XI - Moon 8","73":"YHN-3K XII","74":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 1","75":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 2","76":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 3","77":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 4","78":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 5","79":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 6","80":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 7","81":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 8","82":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 9","83":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 10","84":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 11","85":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 12","86":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 13","87":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 14","88":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 15","89":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 16","90":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 17","91":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 18","92":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 19","93":"YHN-3K XII - Moon 20","94":"YHN-3K XIII","95":"YHN-3K XIII - Moon 1","96":"YHN-3K XIII - Moon 2","97":"YHN-3K XIII - Moon 3"}
```

Comment: I've even tried it with JSON_FORCE_OBJECT removed with no luck. I'm missing something simple I can feel it.

Comment: Do you have any errors popping in your console? I also suggest you use a relative path to get your url instead of the absolute one, since you're in the same folder. Replace `data` for `this` in the following line: `$("<option value='" + data + "'>" + data + "</option>").appendTo("#celestrials");`

Comment: @JeffNoel No errors and using `this` worked on all other tests except my example query _YHN-3K_

Comment: I started thinking maybe it was a cache issue, since other tests worked so I closed browser and reopened and it starting working with my test query. Thanks @JeffNoel!!

Comment: You are welcome. For convenience I also updated my live demos with your full array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

Insert `this` instead of `data` when you create your `<option>` DOMElements.

The error lies in your `$.each()` loop, where you tend to try to put the value of the whole `data` object in your DOMElement everytime you loop.

Try to put only **one** value instead of the whole object.

---

### JQuery - [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/mY3cd/4/)

```
 $.each(data, function() { 
     $("<option value='" + this + "'>" + this + "</option>").appendTo("#celestrials");
 });
```

---

### Pure JavaScript loop - [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/mY3cd/3/)

**Note:** I'm not using the `.length` property since the received object might not necessarily have one. It depends whether it is in a valid format or not. As is, it does not seem to be a JSON Object.

```
for(var i=0; i<Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
    document.querySelector('#celestrials').innerHTML += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>"
}
```

---

[image: SELECT]

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gCFM9/

I suggest this option:

```
for(var i in data) {
   data[i] //each value of i position
}
```

Comment: I agree, and just to build on Jeff's comment, you want to make sure your php is returning an array, not an object.

Comment: Just putting my comment back again (edited): Using a `for ... in` loop has a [**huge performance effect**](http://jsperf.com/array-splicing-pure-vs-jquery) on the script. Try using a regular `for` loop instead.

Comment: @xmarston You are very welcome, for my part, I actualy learnt that last week!

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateCelestrials () {
    // If you are using jQuery - use jQuery.
    var orbs = $('#systemNames').val();

    var myURL = "http://www.domain.com/folder/json.php?solarSystemName=" 
                    // make sure you escape user's input
                    + encodeURIComponent(orbs); 

    $.getJSON(myURL, function(data) {
      // make less DOM actions by storing in local variable 
      // and appending later on
      var items = '';
      $.each(data, function(index, value) { 
        items += "<option value='" + index + "'>" + value + "</option>";
      });
      $("#celestrials").html(items); // beware. this will replace all options :)

      // also avoid using jQuery for no reason when creating 
      // elements with $([html here]).appendTo
    });
}
```

but I'd rather replace $.each with

```
for (var index in data) {
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(index)) { // make sure you are using your properties
       items += "<option value='" + index + "'>" + data[index] + "</option>";
   }
}
```